# Display song lyrics in iTunes (from ID3 tags)

Tags: windows, itunes, mp3, mp3-player, lyrics

I've added lyrics to all the songs in my music library. Now, I'm looking for a way to display those lyrics in iTunes, and falling pretty short.

I've seen a few widgets, but they all seem to focus on getting the lyrics from the internet based on tags. I'd like a widget which pulls the lyrics from the ID3 tag itself.

Preferably, I'd also like to see the lyrics in miniplayer mode.

I'm on Windows, by the way.

Comment: I want that too! It's a surprise that it's not natively supported.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and looked at all the widgets and itunes plugins, the best solution is minilyrics (not free) what's great about this program as that i can read the lyrics from the mp3 id3 tag AND write lyrics from and online source to the mp3 itself.

This is specially useful if you want to read the lyrics on your ipod.

Comment: I second this. MiniLyrics shows you the lyrics while the song plays.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up going with SkiniTunes. It basically gives you an improved mini-player.

The free version supports a mini-player that lets you rate songs (not natively supported), and also view song lyrics. The lyrics box is kinda big and clunky, and you don't have any control over the font, which is a minus. On the plus side though, it does work.

The paid version (which I haven't bought yet) also gives a few other goodies, like giving iTunes support for global shortcuts. I'm planning on buying soon for that alone, after test driving it for a few more days.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into this - [iTunes Companion](http://widgets.yahoo.com/widgets/itunes-companion)